# Only the name value for one parameter and not the next

Tags: java, regex

I have a String which is a String which could be of the format

```
name=tony, age=49, address=france, plan=complete
```

or

```
name=tony, age=49, address="france", plan="complete"
```

or

```
name='tony', age=49, address='france', plan='complete'
```

or

```
name:"tony", age:49, "address":"france", "plan":"complete"
```

or

```
name:"tony", age:49, "address": "france", "plan":"complete"
```

I am trying to match on the various permutation of address = france. I don't need the quote or double quote before address.

In Java, I do:

```
address"['\"]?[:=]['\"]?[^'\"]+['\"]?"
```

But this matches to the end of the String so it includes plan: complete.

Any tips on how I could end the match?  It should look for a commo or if no comma an end of line, or at the very first the next `=` or `:`

Comment: I don't know the answer off the top of my head, but this is a great site for testing RegEx expressions- http://www.infobyip.com/regularexpressioncalculator.php

Hopefully it'll be of some use to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex to match address `france` for all 5 cases:

```
address['"]? *[=:] *['"]?([^'",]+)
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/mH2jX4/2)

Comment: Oh wow, that's a much better site than what I mentioned. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Can you tell me why you need to introduce the capture at the end there? Why not just do: address['"]? *[=:] *['"]?[^'",]+

Comment: You can always take out capturing group if you don't need matched address text like: `address['"]? *[=:] *['"]?[^'",]+`

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to use little more complicated regexp which will allow you find any value in string. Apply this snippets for java regexp dialect.

Find all values:

```
/[=:]\s*['"]?([\w ]+)['"]?(?:,|$)/gm
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aV0zS4/4)

And for some key (f.e. address):

> /\baddress['"]?\s*[=:]\s*['"]?([\w ]+)['"]?(?:,|$)/gm

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aV0zS4/3)

Answer (score 0):

In all cases the address comes between the second and third comma, so you could also do a split;

```
String longstring = "name:\"tony\", age:49, \"address\": \"france\", \"plan\":\"complete\"";        
String splitted[] = longstring.split(",");
String Address = splitted[2];
System.out.println(Address);
```